# Getting BuildContext in Flutter for localization

Tags: dart, flutter

I try to localize a String in Flutter with the localization package. The problem is the location where my translation is needed. It is not related to the UI, rather it is somewhere deep in my model, where I don't have access to a  BuildContext. Is there any other possibility to still make use of the translation function?

```
// I don't have a context variable here
MyLocalizations.of(context).trans("foo")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "context is missing" ?

Comment: But what do you mean by "here"? There should be a way for you to still access a `BuildContext`; even if hidden behind a layer of abstraction.

Comment: How can that work if `BuildContext context` is nowhere declared in my function?

Comment: By using abstract classes and stuff. But I don't know your code so it's hard to answer

Comment: I just found `BuildContext get context => _element;` so context can be used out of the build context. That might indeed help. I will take a look, thanks!

Comment: In your `build` method, which receives a `BuildContext` as a parameter, you can fetch your localizations: `Widget build(BuildContext context) { var loc = MyLocalizations.of(context); … }` then just pass it as a parameter to any other functions called from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no other way because it is stored using an [`InheritedWidget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html), which is a part of the build tree and thus can only be accessed with a reference to it (the `BuildContext`).
You will need to pass your `context` to somewhere deep in your model.

Answer (score 11):

Yes there is. You don't need BuildContext to access strings. Here is my solution:

```
class Strings {
  Strings._(Locale locale) : _localeName = locale.toString() {
    current = this;
  }

  final String _localeName;

  static Strings current;

  static Future<Strings> load(Locale locale) async {
    await initializeMessages(locale.toString());
    final result = Strings._(locale);
    return result;
  }

  static Strings of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<Strings>(context, Strings);
  }

  String get title {
    return Intl.message(
      'Hello World',
      name: 'title',
      desc: 'Title for the Demo application',
    );
  }
}

Future<Null> main() async {
  final Locale myLocale = Locale(window.locale);
  await Strings.load(myLocale);
  runApp(MyApplication());
}
```

Now you can reference a string as follows:

```
final title = Strings.current.title;
```

Comment: Are there any inconveniences using this approach?

Comment: @Martyns If you want to change the current language at runtime by calling `Strings.load` again, you need to reload any strings stored e.g. into class member data. App restart is needed if you have stored strings e.g. into static final variables. No other issues faced so far.

Comment: and what is  `await initializeMessages(locale.toString());` ?

Comment: Please read tutorial [Internation­alizing Flutter apps](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization). `initializeMessages` is part of the generated code.

Comment: @kine thanks. I've generated .arb's and .dart's with messages [en, pl], passed Platform.locale to Locale constructor and checked your solution unfortunatelu with no luck -  calling Strings.current.title keep returning Hello world text set in return Intl.message("Hello wordl"...). tried to change languages few times with the same result. Is it just me or this no longer work ?

Comment: @Matt You said you pass `Platform.locale` to locale constructor. I have not tested with that, my sample code uses `window.locale`. Please try again with that. And change language from your device settings.

Comment: @kine thank you for your feedback - checked window.locale - works fine. Strange as  Platform.localeName returns the same string...
Anyways your solution should be included in official Flutter's doc. Thanks for your contribution to the community

Answer (score 7):

AppLocalitzations needs the context.

You can create a class (e.g., Localization) to encapsulate AppLocalizations initialization and initialize it from the home widget using its context. After, can be used with a mixin:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

class Localization {
  static AppLocalizations _loc;

  AppLocalizations get loc => Localization._loc;

  static void init(BuildContext context) => _loc = AppLocalizations.of(context);
}
```

In the home widget:

```
...
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       Localization.init(context);
       return Scaffold(
...
```

Access to loc in some class (it isn't necessary to be a Widget) using mixins:

```
class XXXWidget extends StatelessWidget with Localization {
    ...
    Text(loc.xxxx)
    ...
}

class _XXXXWidgetState extends State<XXXWidget> with Localization {
    ...
    Text(loc.xxxx)
    ...
}

class XXXXController with Localization {
    ...
    cardNumberValidator = RequiredValidator(errorText: loc.commons_Required);
    ...
}
```

**Null safety version:**

```
class Localization {
  static AppLocalizations? _l;    
  AppLocalizations get loc => Localization._l!;

  static void init(BuildContext context) => _l = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work anymore

Comment: Why not? Is it for null safety? I'm using with a version adapted to null safety and works.

Comment: I am sorry, I am learning Flutter and it's been 11 days since I tried this, I can't remember the scenario to explain. Somehow I managed to make Localizations work.

Comment: I edit the answer and put the null safety version.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is dated way back. But I came across this issue when implementing my application, and I dont see any "nice" way to handle it.
So here is my approach

```
class LanguageService {
  static String defaultLanguage = 'en';

  static Map<String, Map<String, String>> _localizedValues = {
    'en': {
      'title': 'Storefront',
      'language': 'Language',
      'googleLogin': 'Login with Google'
    },
    'vn': {
      'title': 'Cửa hàng',
      'language': 'Ngôn ngữ',
      'googleLogin': 'Đăng Nhập với Google'
    }
  };

  static set language(String lang) {
    defaultLanguage = lang;
  }

  static String get title {
    return _localizedValues[defaultLanguage]['title'];
  }

  static String get language {
    return _localizedValues[defaultLanguage]['language'];
  }

  static String get googleLogin {
    return _localizedValues[defaultLanguage]['googleLogin'];
  }

}
```

Now you can reference a string as follows:

```
String title = LanguageService.title;
```

You can find the detailed tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@itchybumr/flutter-internationalization-the-easy-way-localization-without-buildcontext-f6eb6f2454a)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i did it right (from performance point of view) and maybe someone can comment on this but i have rx BehaviorSubject in my AppLocalization and fire event once new locales are loaded. I am listening to it in my main.dart and doing setState on receiving an event.
I checked performance tab but did not noticed any big changes in it once comparing my method vs accessing translations through context (inherited widget).