# Getting localized strings in the headless mode

Tags: android, flutter, headless

I'm currently trying to run the app in the headless mode and what I did I defined the background callback:

```
void callbackInBackground() {
 // Invoked from the service
}
```

And I'm trying to get my localized strings with the current Locale from the callback.

Since I need the `BuildContext` to do that, I'm not how to retrieve them.

Any tips and tricks for that?

Comment: check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803755/getting-buildcontext-in-flutter-for-localization and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563074/flutter-localization-without-context

Comment: Headless is supposed to be used for testing.

Comment: @mFeinstein but how do then invoke Flutter part from the service when the main app is not running?

Comment: I am not familiar with this, I would say you can't as it wasn't made for this, it was made for a testing environment, not to be used as a background service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) plugin to achieve this. Also, you can use [flutter_background_fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/flutter_background_fetch) plugin for headless execution.

Example for easy_localization :

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'lang_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization_loader/easy_localization_loader.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';

import 'generated/locale_keys.g.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(EasyLocalization(
    child: MyApp(),
    supportedLocales: [
      Locale('en', 'US'),
      Locale('ar', 'DZ'),
      Locale('de', 'DE'),
      Locale('ru', 'RU')
    ],
    path: 'resources/langs/langs.csv', //'resources/langs',
    // fallbackLocale: Locale('en', 'US'),
    // startLocale: Locale('de', 'DE'),
    // saveLocale: false,
    // useOnlyLangCode: true,
    // preloaderColor: Colors.black,
    // preloaderWidget: CustomPreloaderWidget(),

    // optional assetLoader default used is RootBundleAssetLoader which uses flutter's assetloader
    // install easy_localization_loader for enable custom loaders
    // assetLoader: RootBundleAssetLoader()
    // assetLoader: HttpAssetLoader()
    // assetLoader: FileAssetLoader()
    assetLoader: CsvAssetLoader()
    // assetLoader: YamlAssetLoader() //multiple files
    // assetLoader: YamlSingleAssetLoader() //single file
    // assetLoader: XmlAssetLoader() //multiple files
    // assetLoader: XmlSingleAssetLoader() //single file
    // assetLoader: CodegenLoader()
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log(context.locale.toString(),
        name: '${this} # locale Context');
    log('title'.tr().toString(), name: '${this} # locale');
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'title'.tr(),
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
      locale: context.locale,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Easy localization'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int counter = 0;
  bool _gender = true;

  void incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      counter++;
    });
  }

  void switchGender(bool val) {
    setState(() {
      _gender = val;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(LocaleKeys.title).tr(context: context),
        //Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).tr('title')),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.language),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => LanguageView(), fullscreenDialog: true),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Text(
              LocaleKeys.gender_with_arg,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                  fontSize: 19,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ).tr(args: ['aissat'], gender: _gender ? 'female' : 'male'),
            Text(
              tr(LocaleKeys.gender, gender: _gender ? 'female' : 'male'),
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(FontAwesome.male),
                Switch(value: _gender, onChanged: switchGender),
                Icon(FontAwesome.female),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Text(LocaleKeys.msg).tr(args: ['aissat', 'Flutter']),
            Text(LocaleKeys.msg_named).tr(namedArgs: {'lang': 'Dart'}, args: ['Easy localization']),
            Text(LocaleKeys.clicked).plural(counter),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                incrementCounter();
              },
              child: Text(LocaleKeys.clickMe).tr(),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Text(
                plural(LocaleKeys.amount, counter,
                    format: NumberFormat.currency(
                        locale: Intl.defaultLocale, symbol: '€')),
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                context.deleteSaveLocale();
              },
              child: Text(LocaleKeys.reset_locale).tr(),
            ),
            Spacer(
              flex: 1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: incrementCounter,
        child: Text('+1'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomPreloaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomPreloaderWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log('Loading custom preloder widget');
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a library for localization **flutter_localizations** you can use that.

Also I'm sharing code you can directly use it and modify as per your requirement.
you need to add to json file in lang folder, All string are availabe in these json file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

import 'app_localizations.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // List all of the app's supported locales here
      supportedLocales: [
        Locale('en', 'US'),
        Locale('sk', 'SK'),
      ],
      // These delegates make sure that the localization data for the proper language is loaded
      localizationsDelegates: [
        // A class which loads the translations from JSON files
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        // Built-in localization of basic text for Material widgets
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        // Built-in localization for text direction LTR/RTL
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      // Returns a locale which will be used by the app
      localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
        // Check if the current device locale is supported
        for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
          if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode &&
              supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
            return supportedLocale;
          }
        }
        // If the locale of the device is not supported, use the first one
        // from the list (English, in this case).
        return supportedLocales.first;
      },
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('first_string'),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('second_string'),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                'This will not be translated.',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

app_localizations.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class AppLocalizations {
  final Locale locale;

  AppLocalizations(this.locale);

  // Helper method to keep the code in the widgets concise
  // Localizations are accessed using an InheritedWidget "of" syntax
  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of<AppLocalizations>(context, AppLocalizations);
  }

  // Static member to have a simple access to the delegate from the MaterialApp
  static const LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> delegate =
      _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  Map<String, String> _localizedStrings;

  Future<bool> load() async {
    // Load the language JSON file from the "lang" folder
    String jsonString =
        await rootBundle.loadString('lang/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);

    _localizedStrings = jsonMap.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
    });

    return true;
  }

  // This method will be called from every widget which needs a localized text
  String translate(String key) {
    return _localizedStrings[key];
  }
}

// LocalizationsDelegate is a factory for a set of localized resources
// In this case, the localized strings will be gotten in an AppLocalizations object
class _AppLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
  // This delegate instance will never change (it doesn't even have fields!)
  // It can provide a constant constructor.
  const _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    // Include all of your supported language codes here
    return ['en', 'sk'].contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    // AppLocalizations class is where the JSON loading actually runs
    AppLocalizations localizations = new AppLocalizations(locale);
    await localizations.load();
    return localizations;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(_AppLocalizationsDelegate old) => false;
}
```