# How to use Flutter Localization without context?

Tags: flutter, localization

I'm using flutter_localizations.dart package to Localize my App in different Languages. Usually, I use `S.of(context).wordToLocalize` to call the String according to each language.

However, in the login process, I have no context, so I cannot use the same procedure. I I have the following error:

> Undefined name 'context'. Try correcting the name to one that is
> defined, or defining the name.

The code where I need to use it, is as follows

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:aplians_fish/generated/l10n.dart';

    
class Validators {

final validarEmail = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
  handleData: (email, sink) {

    Pattern pattern = r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
    if (regExp.hasMatch(email)) {
      sink.add(email);
    } else {
      sink.addError('It must be a valid e-mail'); 

// I would like to change the previous line for S.of(context).validEmail

    }
  }
);
```

How can I call Flutter Localization in this code?

Comment: Did you try this solutions ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563074/flutter-localization-without-context

Comment: Yes, I saw it. However, I am using a package to auto-generate l10n.dart so I am not comfortable with manual changes on this side.

Comment: Try use get_it https://stackoverflow.com/a/68390265/699604

Comment: This is my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69037938/1034225

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize `Validators` with a BuildContext for the Localization.

```dart
class Validators {
  Validators({required BuildContext context}) 
      :  _context = context;

  final BuildContext _context;

  // You can now call BuildContext inside Validators like
  // AppLocalizations.of(_context).validEmail
}
```

The class can be initialized in `Widget build()` where BuildContext can be passed.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext buildContext) {
  Validators(context: buildContext);
  return Scaffold(...);
}
```